# Proving $A=0$ and $B$ is positive definite given $||A||<1$ and block matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix  with $\|A\|<1$.
>   Suppose that the matrix,
>
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> 0 & A \\
> A^T & B 
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> is positive semidefinite. Show that $A=0$ and that $B$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 7):

Since the matrix is positive semidefinite, we get
$$
0\le\pmatrix{0\\x}^T \pmatrix{ 0 & A\\A^T&B} \pmatrix{0\\x} = x^TBx,
$$
hence $B$ is positive semidefinite. 
Similarly, it follows
$$
0\le\pmatrix{y\\x}^T \pmatrix{ 0 & A\\A^T&B} \pmatrix{y\\x} = x^TBx + 2y^TAx
$$
for all $x,y$.

Suppose there is $x$ with $Ax\ne0$. Then we set $y:= \lambda \cdot Ax$. using this in the above inequality implies
$$
0 \le x^TBx + 2 \lambda \|Ax\|^2
$$
for all $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. Sending $\lambda\to-\infty$ yields a contradiction. Hence $Ax=0$ for all $x$. We can conclude $A=0$ by choosing $x$ to be $e_1, e_2, ..., e_m$, where the $e_i$'s are $n \times 1$ unit vectors with $1$ in the $ith$ position and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Did you use $$||A|| < 1$$? If so, where?

Comment: @BCLC no, this assumption does not help anything.